# How to convert string to key to be used in encryption?

Tags: java-me, cryptography, key, blowfish

Hi All
I want to convert the string (taken as input from user) into a secretkey.I am coding in J2ME.The algorithm used is blowfish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java cryptography APIs are not available in Java ME.

You'll need to download the [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) lightweight cryptography API, which supports Java ME. You can then extract the classes you need from there. I found a code example [here](http://arylson.lowlevel.com.br/?p=20) that should help you get started.

About charsets: Java ME does indeed support UTF-8, so that's always a safe bet. And a good idea, yes, although you'll see a lot of code that doesn't specify a charset.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Please see Eric's answer. This is not available in J2ME.**

To convert a string to a key, you can do:

```
String strkey = "My key goes here";
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(strkey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "Blowfish");
```

Comment: No, don't do that.  Never use the no-args `String.getBytes()` for applications like this. Always specify a Charset, and almost always you can use UTF-8. Also the SecretKeySpec class is not available on J2ME.

Comment: What's available on J2ME? I can remove this answer, but I don't want to lose your comment.